# Get the last response from a Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am working on a script to get the last form submission. I found the vanilla example online...

```
function onSubmit() {
  // Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1G3e4FTYlsJUl5mKX2v1pYWauG1FO5IUPDIOI6P4hUoA');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();
 for (var i = 0; i < formResponses.length; i++) {
   var formResponse = formResponses[i];
   var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();
   for (var j = 0; j < itemResponses.length; j++) {
     var itemResponse = itemResponses[j];
     Logger.log('Response #%s to the question "%s" was "%s"',
         (i + 1).toString(),
         itemResponse.getItem().getTitle(),
         itemResponse.getResponse());
   }
 }
}
```

I have modified this to...

```
function onSubmit() {
  // Open a form by ID and log the responses to each question.
 var form = FormApp.openById('1G3e4FTYlsJUl5mKX2v1pYWauG1FO5IUPDIOI6P4hUoA');
 var formResponses = form.getResponses();

 var last_response = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1];
  Logger.log(last_response.val)
}
```

When I view the log for the script above I get `undefined`. How do I output the value of last_response?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to use the `getItemResponses()` method.  The `getItemResponses()` method gets all the "Items" of one Form submission.  Most of the Items are the questions.  But there are Items that are not questions, like PAGE_BREAK.  So you need to exclude things like page breaks.  I've called the Items in this code Questions, but Items are not always questions.

```
function getArrayOfOneSubmissionsAnswers() {
  var allQuestions,i,itemType,L,thisAnswer,thisQuestion,thisSubmissionsAnswers;
    //Define all variables without assigning a value - value at this point
    //is undefined

  allQuestions = FormApp.openById('your_Form_ID').getResponses()[0].getItemResponses();

  L = allQuestions.length;//How many questions are there in the Form
  thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];//Create an empty array for answers

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop through all the questions in this Form submission
    thisQuestion = allQuestions[i];//Get this question

    itemType = thisQuestion.getItem().getType();

    if (itemType === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      continue;//keep looping
    };

    thisAnswer = thisQuestion.getResponse();//Get the answer
    Logger.log(i + " - " + thisAnswer); 

    thisSubmissionsAnswers.push(thisAnswer);//add answer to the array
  };

  Logger.log("thisSubmissionsAnswers: " + thisSubmissionsAnswers); 

  return thisSubmissionsAnswers;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for posterity here is a slightly modified version of Sandy's script above that give me the last response submitted from a form.

```
function getArrayOfLastSubmissionsAnswers() {
  var allQuestions,i,itemType,L,thisAnswer,thisQuestion,thisSubmissionsAnswers,number_of_submissions;
    //Define all variables without assigning a value - value at this point
    //is undefined

  number_of_submissions = FormApp.openById('your_Form_ID').getResponses().length;
  allQuestions = FormApp.openById('your_Form_ID').getResponses()[number_of_submissions - 1].getItemResponses();

  L = allQuestions.length;//How many questions are there in the Form
  thisSubmissionsAnswers = [];//Create an empty array for answers

  for (i=0;i<L;i++) {//Loop through all the questions in this Form submission
    thisQuestion = allQuestions[i];//Get this question

    itemType = thisQuestion.getItem().getType();

    if (itemType === FormApp.ItemType.PAGE_BREAK) {
      continue;//keep looping
    };

    thisAnswer = thisQuestion.getResponse();//Get the answer
    Logger.log(i + " - " + thisAnswer); 

    thisSubmissionsAnswers.push(thisAnswer);//add answer to the array
  };

  Logger.log("thisSubmissionsAnswers: " + thisSubmissionsAnswers); 

  return thisSubmissionsAnswers;
};
```